# Getting 415 status error while call WCF service using jquery ajax for PhoneGap Android Application from a intranet hosted service on a Windows server

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, wcf, http-status-code-415

I am trying to consume WCF service in a PhoneGap application for Android using jquery ajax which is hosted in a intranet domain.

As a response  I am getting  message based on my ajax request in the below.

**Ajax Request:**

```
    $.ajax({ 

        url: "http://myIP/wcfService.svc/myFun",
        type: "POST",  

        data: JSON.stringify(req),
        dataType: "json",

        success: OnSuccess,

        error: function(xhr,err){
            alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
            alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

**Request Header**

> ```
>  Accept   application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
>  Accept-Encoding  gzip, deflate
>  Accept-Language  en-US,en;q=0.5
>  Cache-Control    no-cache
>  Connection   keep-alive
>  Content-Length   39
>  Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
>  DNT  1
>  Host MyIP
>  Origin   null
>  Pragma   no-cache
>  User-Agent   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
> ```

**Response Header**

> HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type
>   'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' was not the
>   expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.
>
> Cache-Control: private
>
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
>
> X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>
> X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, origin, content-type,
>   accept
>
> Date: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 16:26:25 GMT
>
> Content-Length: 0

**Error Status:**

> 415 Cannot process the message because the content type
>   'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' was not the
>   expected type 'text/xml; char

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403492/cannot-process-the-message-because-the-content-type-application-json-charset-u

Comment: Already check with the solution.. but not worked for me... Anyways thanks..

Comment: Mhh but it looks like your service endpoint cant accept webform data.. Please post your binding config, or check messageEncoding property on binding.

Comment: <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"
            Service="YourNamespace.YourServiceClass"
            Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>

Comment: @Nemo I suggest you to look at the last comment in this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26625191/http-415-cannot-process-the-message-because-the-content-type-application-json It says use webHttpBinding  instead of basicHttpBinding for JSON Hope it may help

Comment: @gandhi, tried your given solution but the service is not accessible..

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
$.ajax({ 

    url: "http://myIP/wcfService.svc/myFun",
    type: "POST",  

    data: JSON.stringify(req),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",

    success: OnSuccess,

    error: function(xhr,err){
        alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
        alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```